# Detecting a signal to meet criteria

Tags: fpga

Not sure if this belongs here.

Using FPGA:

Lets say I get a trigger input to my system.

I want to declare that an edge is part of my signal if I get it every X \$ \mu \$s time. (lets say 1\$ \mu \$s)

4 triggers at X \$ \mu \$s time is enough to output OK.

More specific: lets say x is timeline y is a trigger I get. The trigger could be a valid signal I get or may be noise. Lets say they look the same. The only way I can recognize a valid input signal is by detecting it 4 times separated by 1\$ \mu \$s time. Input could be anything: 1___1_1___1___11_111_1__1 each of these '1' (which represent an input trigger) could be end/part/start of a valid signal or noise. How can I implement this? The simple choice would be to start a counter for every edge I get, and start following it. Any other ideas?

Edit:
I get an input to the FPGA from a comparator. 
High input means detection
Example: 
S-high input which is the signal i want to detect
N-high input which is not the signal-noise

N__S__NNNSN__NS___NSNN__S
signal is identified by getting high input at a spesific interval ( here every 5 units)
Anything can happen in between. Might be quiet, and might be sporadic.

Answer (score 1):

Counting certainly is a valid method.

Another way without counting would be to feed your signal into a 4 bit shift register, use a logical AND on all the four bits and use this as an input to your detector. It only is 1, if there are four 1s in the shift register.

Of course, in both situations there might be a situation where two valid inputs follow each other directly, i.e. you have eight 1 in a row as an input. In this case you have to specify what the output should look like (1 for the whole time after the first four 1s were detected, or two separate 1s, each spaced by three 0s...). If the later is desired, you could use the output of the ANDs as an input to the shift register's reset port to clear all its bits.

Comment: The main issue is the time between pulses. Its not enough to get a pulse. I need 4 pulses with 1us delay between them. How can i detect that withouth starting a counter fir each and every pulse i get?

Comment: I see. In this case, I think it would be best if you could update your question and be a bit more elaborate on your signal and sampling/measurement hardware. Please give examples of how signals look, maybe some extreme/problematic cases (i.e. might there be 1s between two of the 1s that are 1 us separated and could make up the signal?).

Comment: I edited the original post. Hope it clarifies a bit more. The main issue is the every input i get is a suspect to be the signal. Only when i track it and identify it has another suspect at 1us later and then again, i can be sure this is my signal and not some random noise

Comment: @Dan You need to keep a number of detectors in parallel, and determine detection based on any of them finding the pattern you want.